# Grid View Layout for images in the wordpress

Tags: php, image, wordpress, layout, gridview

I have many page in my website, but in one of my page, I am adding only images. Now I want to display this images in a grid view something similar to this site [SITE](http://www.matchbookmag.com/press/) . 
How can achieve that? And also right now all the images have link attached to it. If user click on any image, respective site will loaded, but problem is how to load those site in new tab?. As of now they are getting loaded in same tab in which I am clicking on images.

Please help me solves this problem, as I'm beginner in `wordpress`.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the most efficient way to solve your problem is by using some plugins which are freely available to download and use.

Here is one such plugin, [wordpress plugin link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gallery-custom-links/) which solves your both the problems.

Just login has as Admin to word press on your website, download the plugin and activate it. You can follow rest of the instructions how to use this plugin as given in the source site.

Answer (score 0):

hi list all images in table view so it's look like nice formatting and for open link in new tab please try this `<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">click here</a>`

Read this for more details
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: my requirement is different,In my case client admin will dynamically add images and attach respective site url to those images. So don't about codes. They will only use interface in wordpress to do all this things.

Comment: Right now I am Uploading image and setting url from **ATTACHMENT** DISPLAY SETTINGS → **Link To**

Comment: find location(in code) and set target='_blank' in <a> tag. and for grid view set div before and after of images and apply css on the given div class.